# Relationship Between same numerical values

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, number-comparison

Let me explain my scenario. I am calculating the percentage of prepositions per document. In beginning, I have taken 20 mobile phone blogs and my mean preposition percentage in 20 blog documents comes out to be 11.61%. Now I have to compare this mean value to the percentage of prepositions in single document lets say it is 10.55%. Now I have to compare these two values i.e 11.61% and 10.55% so as to tell that how much single document deviates from standard data. Can someone suggest me some metric, that would enable me to calculate the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$11.61\% - 10.55\%=1.06\%$  This is a flip answer, but it is meant to indicate that you need to think about what you are trying to measure.  A traditional approach would be to compute the standard deviation of your sample and say that the individual one was so many sigma away from the mean.  While that is a well defined calculation, it tends to make people assume the distribution is normal, which is probably not the case.  Another approach would be to say the individual one was $35$th percentile or some such.  As it relies on counting instead of standard deviation, it is a more robust statistic.  Maybe you just found my blog that is just a list of prepositions.  Your standard deviation will increase a lot, but the percentile won't change much.

Comment: Thank you for pondering at my cause. But in this case, the 20 mobile blogs which I have chosen for prepositions are the standard blogs with the mean percentage of preposition to be 11.61%. The single blog in which the percentage of prepositions is 10.55 % is uploaded by a user who is new to blogging. I need to compare the standard data with the data in the user's document ( percentage of preposition). Can you explain in detail how should I proceed?

Comment: I suggested three different metrics.  The raw difference in percentage, the number of standard deviations from the mean and the percentile ranking relative to the other blogs, which would be 50 if this blog were perfectly average.  All of them are fine ways to measure the difference, but they have different properties.  The choice among them (or to use something else) depends on what you want to reflect.